# Does IBM Cloud Speech to Text have a Swagger (Open API) 2.0 Schema?

Tags: swagger, ibm-cloud, openapi, swagger-2.0

I've seen a number of SDKs in the IBM Cloud for Speech to Text but not a document with the JSON Schema for something like OpenAPI 2.0 (Swagger). We need to use that in our case. Does that exist?

Comment: Not a complete answer to your question but maybe a starter: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=go#introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the warning mentioned in the [link](https://watson-api-explorer.ng.bluemix.net)

> "IBM provides these older versions of the Watson APIs in Swagger
> version 2.0 format (the "Swagger APIs"). You may use the Swagger APIs
> to provide capabilities or integrations that leverage the older
> versions of the APIs. The Swagger APIs are provided as-is, and IBM
> does not make any commitments about the quality, reliability,
> availability, or ability of the Swagger APIs to meet your needs.

In short, The OpenAPI 2.0 specifications are deprecated and are not maintained.

You can use the API docs as [documented here](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text)

If you still want Swagger(OpenAPI 2.0) schema, here are the steps

**Disclaimer**: **Not recommended**. For viewing the schema only

1. Download the old Swagger OpenAPI 2.0 JSON file from [here](https://watson-api-explorer.ng.bluemix.net/speech-to-text-v1.json).
2. Create an account on [Swagger IO](https://swagger.io).
3. Create New --> Import the JSON to create an API